# neo4j server becomes very slow when creating nodes and relations

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, pycharm, ram

For testing purposes, I'm using a Windows 7 laptop with the following specs: [image]

I also use neo4j-enterprise-3.0.2 and connect my Pycharm python program to the database using the BOLT connection. I create many nodes and relations. I noticed that the creation of nodes and relations slows down tremendously after a certain time and almost does not progress after a certain point.

I checked the following

- I use unique constraints on nodes and properties so that schema-indexing is available to easily find nodes in the database
- I noticed that my RAM memory keeps increasing while all these transactions take place. I used different setting in the neo4j config file for dbms.memory.pagecache.size  (default, 2g, 3g, 10g) and They all cause my RAM to increase from around 4GB (no python code running) up to 7GB and above. That's when the creation of nodes get very slow. When stopping the program, the RAM usage drops again.

[image]

This is what the health monitor shows me:

[image]

Question: why does the creation of nodes and relations slows down so much? Is it due to the graph size (but the data set seems rather small for that)? Is it related to the BOLT connections and transactions to the database? Is it related to the increased RAM usage? How can this be prevented?

I created this simple example to show the problem:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase

#BOLT driver
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost")
session = driver.session()

#start with empty database
stmtDel = "MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r"
session.run(stmtDel)

#Add uniqueness constraint
stmt = 'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:Day) ASSERT d.name IS UNIQUE'
session.run(stmt)

# Create many nodes - run either option 1 or option 2
# # Option 1: Creates a node one by one. This is slow in execution and keeps the RAM flat (no increase)
# for i in range(1,80001):
#     stmt1 = 'CREATE (d:Day) SET d.name = {name}'
#     dict = {"name": str(i)}
#     print(i)
#     session.run(stmt1,dict)

#Option 2: Increase the speed and submit multiple transactions at the same time - e.g.1000
# This is very fast but blows up the RAM memory in no time, even with a limit on the page cache of 2GB
tx = session.begin_transaction()
for i in range(1, 80001):
    stmt1 = 'CREATE (d:Day) SET d.name = {name}'
    dict = {"name": str(i)}
    tx.run(stmt1, dict) # append a transaction to the block
    print(i)
    if divmod(i,1000)[1] == 0:   #every one thousand transactions submit the block and creat an new transaction block
        tx.commit()
        tx.close
        tx = session.begin_transaction()  #it seems that recycling the session keeps on growing the RAM.
```

Comment: Can you share the python code?

Comment: William, I added a simple example in the question. That shows what causes the problem. It is transaction related I believe. i must be doing something wrong there.

Comment: Btw. on your setting a page-cache of 250M or at most 1G should be good enough. It seems to be something about the tx/session mgmt of the  python driver. Which version do you use?

Comment: For my Pycharm Project the python interpreter used is 3.4.3 and the neo4j-driver is version 1.0.1

Comment: when I populate the transaction block using the py2neo and append commands then I have speedy execution and I do not have the RAM issue. I tried it with the example and also with my much more complex python code. Py2neo works fine and allows me to create hundreds of thousands of nodes but the module neo4j.v1 blows up the memory. A neo4j.v1 bug???

Comment: Did you find any resolution to this? I am experiencing similar behavior in my application during bulk processing. I am not using the transaction method however. (I simply call `session.run(a_statement)` over and over before calling `session.close()` at the end.) Since my bulk processing method does this ~58 million times, my memory usage explodes. It seems like every transaction / statement is saved, and actually committed during `session.close()'. I would expect your transaction method here to mitigate this, but it seems that it doesn't.

Comment: I actually switched back to the py2neo package for the bulk transaction processing and that worked fine without overloading my memory. I believe there must be a problem with the neo4j.v1 package and memory management.

Comment: @GoofyGert I suggest you post your replacement as answer, it helped me, but only because I kept on reading all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

What I first did: I actually switched back to the py2neo package for the bulk transaction processing and that worked fine without overloading my memory. I believe there must be a problem with the neo4j.v1 package and memory management.

Later on: I used a later version of the neo4j package and that did not have the issue anymore. It must have been a bug in the earlier version.